# Java Web Start application blocked by security settings if launched from one server but not another

Tags: java, java-web-start

I don't know if anyone can spread any light on this but basically we have a java web start application which works just fine and is signed by a valid certificate. 
I'm trying to move the code over onto a new test machine and all seems fine except it won't launch, just shows the message:

```
----------------------------------------------------
'Application Blocked by Security Settings
Name: [app name]
Location: [address]
The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel.'
----------------------------------------------------
```

The site it launches from has a self signed certificate, but this is the case also for my dev machine which the app launches from fine. It also works perfectly from our live site so I'm at a bit of a loss as to the cause/cure.

Changing the settings in the Java Control panel has no effect, neither does adding the site to the exception list (I've also tried with port number appended).

Both windows 7 and windows 8 client machines display the same behavior (i.e launches from my dev machine not the test one) the code is identical, it's the same jar and it's signed by a genuine Thwaite cert.
I tried turning on logging and tracing but just get an empty log file and a .trace file
with

```
'Log started: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 13:57:42 +0100
Java Web Start 10.67.2.01
Using JRE version
 1.7.0_67-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM'
```

Any help would be appreciated, i.e. what exactly is the cause of the issue?

Or where could I find the information as this is a fairly unhelpful error message?

Is the certificate for the site the WS app is launched from even a part of the check, or does it just check the jar signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that whilst I'd added the new codebase address to all the library jars the app uses, I hadn't added it correctly to the main jar. As it turns out a manifest codebase mismatch is reported in the console for a library jar but not for the main jar file. It just fails as ours did and gives no clue.

To add the codebase in netbeans just add it to the manifest.custom.codebase property in project.properties.